# What is ->* operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-arrow-star

C++ continues to surprise me.
Today i found out about the ->* operator. It is overloadable but i have no idea how to invoke it. I manage to overload it in my class but i have no clue how to call it.

```
struct B { int a; };

struct A
{
    typedef int (A::*a_func)(void);
    B *p;
    int a,b,c;
    A() { a=0; }
    A(int bb) { b=b; c=b; }
    int operator + (int a) { return 2; }
    int operator ->* (a_func a) { return 99; }
    int operator ->* (int a) { return 94; }
    int operator * (int a) { return 2; }
    B* operator -> () { return p; }


    int ff() { return 4; }
};


void main()
{
    A a;
    A*p = &a;
    a + 2;
}
```

edit:

Thanks to the answer. To call the overloaded function i write

```
void main()
{
    A a;
    A*p = &a;
    a + 2;
    a->a;
    A::a_func f = &A::ff;
    (&a->*f)();
    (a->*f); //this
}
```

Comment: No, you don't call the overloaded operator in this case. What you call is the built-in one. Your overloaded operator requires an `int` as the second parameter.

Comment: @AndreyT: Updating the struct to reflect the new main.

Comment: @acidzombie24: OK, now you finally calling the overloaded version. Again, you could do it without any updates by doing `a->*42`, as sellibitze suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The overloaded `->*` operator is a binary operator (while `.*` is not overloadable). It is interpreted as an ordinary binary operator, so in you original case in order to call that operator you have to do something like

```
A a;
B* p = a->*2; // calls A::operator->*(int)
```

What you read in the Piotr's answer applies to the *built-in* operators, not to your overloaded one. What you call in your added example is also the *built-in* operator, not your overloaded one. In order to call the overloaded operator you have to do what I do in my example above.

Comment: Your right about piotr answer but with it i figured out how to call the overloaded operator as shown in my edited question

Answer (score 17):

Just like `.*`, `->*` is used with pointers to members. There's an entire section [on C++ FAQ LITE](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) dedicated to pointers-to-members.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    void bar(void) { std::cout << "foo::bar" << std::endl; }
    void baz(void) { std::cout << "foo::baz" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void) {
    foo *obj = new foo;
    void (foo::*ptr)(void);

    ptr = &foo::bar;
    (obj->*ptr)();
    ptr = &foo::baz;
    (obj->*ptr)();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like any other opperator, you can also call it explicitly:

```
a.operator->*(2);
```