# What are the pointer-to-member operators ->* and .* in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, pointer-to-member, operator-arrow-star

Yes, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779685/what-is-operator-in-c) and  [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html), but I *still* don't understand what `->*` and `.*` mean in C++.
Those pages provide information *about* the operators (such as overloading), but don't seem to explain well what they *are*.

What are `->*` and `.*` in C++, and when do you need to use them as compared to `->` and `.`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I hope this example will clear things for you

```
//we have a class
struct X
{
   void f() {}
   void g() {}
};

typedef void (X::*pointer)();
//ok, let's take a pointer and assign f to it.
pointer somePointer = &X::f;
//now I want to call somePointer. But for that, I need an object
X x;
//now I call the member function on x like this
(x.*somePointer)(); //will call x.f()
//now, suppose x is not an object but a pointer to object
X* px = new X;
//I want to call the memfun pointer on px. I use ->*
(px ->* somePointer)(); //will call px->f();
```

Now, you can't use `x.somePointer()`, or `px->somePointer()` because there is no such member in class X. For that the special member function pointer call syntax is used... just try a few examples yourself ,you'll get used to it

Comment: Add the **required** extra braces to compensate for operator precedence.

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function *may* be bigger than a regular pointer-to-function: specifically to cope with inheritance iirc

Comment: Think of it as a "relative" pointer: relative to an object -- which you'll then have to provide to actually reach the final destination.

Comment: It's really good explanation and what are they. But I don't really why and when we would need such a thing though.

Comment: Similar to @Sz. said, it (`&X::f`) is an "offset". See Sergey's comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468826/10027592) answer. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586275/10027592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586401/10027592) answers also mention "offset".

Comment: @Useless Why A pointer-to-member-function may be bigger than a regular pointer-to-function?

Comment: Because there may be extra machinery required to deal correctly with pointer-to _virtual_ member-function. The details are implementation details, like everything else about exactly how virtual dispatch works.

Answer (score 31):

EDIT: By the way, it gets weird for [virtual member functions pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx).

For member variables:

```
struct Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
};


int main ()
{
    Foo foo;
    int (Foo :: * ptr);

    ptr = & Foo :: a;
    foo .*ptr = 123; // foo.a = 123;

    ptr = & Foo :: b;
    foo .*ptr = 234; // foo.b = 234;
}
```

Member functions are almost the same.

```
struct Foo {
   int a ();
   int b ();
};


int main ()
{
    Foo foo;
    int (Foo :: * ptr) ();

    ptr = & Foo :: a;
    (foo .*ptr) (); // foo.a ();

    ptr = & Foo :: b;
    (foo .*ptr) (); // foo.b ();
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing that the syntax applies to all members, not just member functions. I find that pointers to member variables are very rarely used, though, despite their many rather interesting potential applications.

Answer (score 19):

In a nutshell: You use `->` and `.` if you know what member you want to access. And you use `->*` and `.*` if you *don't* know what member you want to access.

Example with a simple intrusive list

```
template<typename ItemType>
struct List {
  List(ItemType *head, ItemType * ItemType::*nextMemPointer)
  :m_head(head), m_nextMemPointer(nextMemPointer) { }

  void addHead(ItemType *item) {
    (item ->* m_nextMemPointer) = m_head;
    m_head = item;
  }

private:
  ItemType *m_head;

  // this stores the member pointer denoting the 
  // "next" pointer of an item
  ItemType * ItemType::*m_nextMemPointer;
};
```

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, though never in my life have I *not* known which member I want to access, haha. :)

Comment: I don't understand your code. Can you explain it?

Comment: @mohammad i recommend opening a new question, if you don't understand my comment and explanation I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

So called "pointers" to members in C++ are more like offsets, internally. You need both such a member "pointer", and an object, to reference the member in the object. But member "pointers" are used with pointer syntax, hence the name.

There are two ways you can have an object at hand: you have a reference to the object, or you have a pointer to the object.

For the reference, use `.*` to combine it with a member pointer, and for the pointer, use `->*` to combine it with a member pointer.

However, as a rule, don't use member pointers if you can avoid it.

They obey pretty counter-intuitive rules, and they make it possible to circumvent `protected` access without any explicit casting, that is, inadvertently…

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1 for explaining it well without code. :) Question: Why can't we just take the address of the function like that of a normal function? Is the pointer to a member function different from a pointer to some other function? (e.g. is it bigger?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you could have a pointer to member function that was restricted to non-virtual member functions, then it could indeed just be the address. However, the virtual-ness or not is not part of the member function pointer type. And so its representation needs to include some information about whether the current value refers to a virtual function or not, and if virtual, for a vtable-based implementation information that determines an offset in the vtable of the class the pointer type is associated with.

Answer (score 11):

When you have a normal pointer (to an object or a basic type), you would use `*` to dereference it:

```
int a;
int* b = a;
*b = 5;     // we use *b to dereference b, to access the thing it points to
```

Conceptually, we're doing the same thing with a member function pointer:

```
class SomeClass
{
   public:  void func() {}
};

// typedefs make function pointers much easier.
// this is a pointer to a member function of SomeClass, which takes no parameters and returns void
typedef void (SomeClass::*memfunc)();

memfunc myPointer = &SomeClass::func;

SomeClass foo;

// to call func(), we could do:
foo.func();

// to call func() using our pointer, we need to dereference the pointer:
foo.*myPointer();
// this is conceptually just:    foo  .  *myPointer  ();


// likewise with a pointer to the object itself:
SomeClass* p = new SomeClass;

// normal call func()
p->func();

// calling func() by dereferencing our pointer:
p->*myPointer();
// this is conceptually just:    p  ->  *myPointer  ();
```

I hope that helps explain the concept.  We're effectively dereferencing our pointer to the member function.  It's a little more complicated than that -- it's not an absolute pointer to a function in memory, but just an offset, which is applied to `foo` or `p` above.  But conceptually, we're dereferencing it, much like we would dereference a normal object pointer.

Comment: Trying to compile gives `must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function...` error. This is due to the function call `()` taking precedence over the member-by-pointer operator. I think this can be fixed by adding parenthesis   `(foo.*myPointer)();` and `(p->*myPointer)();`, respectively.

Answer (score 9):

#### Pointer-to-member access operators: `.*` and `->*`

The pointer-to-member access operators, `.*` and `->*`, are for dereferencing a *pointer to member* in combination with an *object* and a *pointer to object*, respectively. This description applies to both *pointers to data members* and *pointers to member functions*.

For example, consider the class `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
   int i;
   void f();
};
```

If you declare a member pointer, `iPtr`, to an `int` data member of `Foo`:

```
int Foo::* iPtr;
```

You can initialize this member pointer `iPtr` so that it points to the `Foo::i` member:

```
iPtr = &Foo::i;
```

To dereference this pointer, you need to use it in conjunction with a `Foo` object.

Consider now the object `foo` and the pointer to object `fooPtr`:

```
Foo foo;
Foo* fooPtr = &foo;
```

Then, you can dereference `iPtr` in combination with `foo` or `fooPtr`:

```
foo.*iPtr = 0;
fooPtr->*iPtr = 0;
```

Analogously, you can use `.*` and `->*` with *pointers to function members*. Note however that you will need to enclose them between parentheses because the *function call operator*, i.e., `()`, has higher precedence than both `.*` and `->*`:

```
void (Foo::*memFuncPtr)() = &Foo::f;

(foo.*memFuncPtr)();
(fooPtr->*memFuncPtr)();
```

To conclude: you need an object to dereference a pointer to a member, and which one you use, either `.*` or `->*` for dereferencing the pointer to member, depends on whether this needed object is directly provided or through an object pointer.

#### C++17 — Using `std::invoke()` instead

The use of both operators can be replaced since C++17 by the [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) function template. `std::invoke` provides a unified way of dereferencing member pointers regardless of whether you use them in combination with an *object* or an *object pointer*, and also regardless of whether the *pointer to member* corresponds to a *pointer to data member* or *pointer to member function*:

```
// dereference a pointer to a data member
std::invoke(iPtr, foo) = 0;      // with an object
std::invoke(iPtr, fooPtr) = 0;   // with an object pointer

// dereference a pointer to a member function
std::invoke(memFuncPtr, foo);      // with an object
std::invoke(memFuncPtr, fooPtr);   // with an object pointer
```

This unified syntax corresponds to the ordinary function call syntax, and it may make it easier to write generic code.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot dereference pointer to members as normal pointers — because member functions require `this` pointer, and you have to pass it somehow. So, you need to use these two operators, with object on one side, and pointer on another, e.g. `(object.*ptr)()`.

Consider using `function` and `bind` (`std::` or `boost::`, depending on whether you write C++03 or 0x) instead of those, though.

Comment: I think this may be the best explanation here.