# What exactly is the ->* operator?

Tags: c++, operators

I've never used it before and just stumbled upon it in an article... I thought it would be the equivalent to `*x->y` but apparently it isn't.

Here's what I tried, and gave me an error:

```
struct cake {
 int * yogurt;
} * pie;

int main(void) {
 pie = new cake;
 pie->yogurt = new int;
 return pie->*yogurt = 4;
}
```

Comment: It is primarily used for method pointers and function member pointers.

Comment: Ok, but can someone actually explain its use and/or provide an example code that uses it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Pointer-to-Member ->\* and .\* Operators in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c) (That one is dated earlier than this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its used when you have pointers to member functions.

When you have a pointer to a function of a class, you call it in much the same way you would call any member function

object.membername( ... )

or

objectptr->membername( ... )

but when you have a member function pointer, an extra * is needed after the . or -> in order that the compiler understand that what comes next is a variable, not the actual name of the function to call.

Here's an example of how its used.

```
class Duck
{
public:

  void quack() { cout << "quack" << endl; }
  void waddle() { cout << "waddle" << endl; }
};

typedef void (Duck::*ActionPointer)();

ActionPointer myaction = &Duck::quack;

void takeDuckAction()
{    
    Duck myduck;
    Duck *myduckptr = &myduck;

    (myduck.*myaction)();
    (myduckptr->*myaction)();
}
```

Comment: I get it, so it's used along with the `::*` for nonstatic member function pointers. Thanks.

Comment: @myrkos yep, updated the answer a bit to make that more clear

Comment: @Ben, ok, but when would that actually be useful rather than plain pointer dereferencing?

Comment: @myrkos: A member pointer is used when the target object is chosen long after the pointer is created.  For example, you could make a sort function that takes an array of structures and a pointer-to-member, and uses that to extract the sort field from each element.  A functor is generally more powerful than a pointer-to-member, but not always as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

It defines a [pointer to a member](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).

> In an expression containing the –>* operator, the first operand must
>   be of the type "pointer to the class type" of the type specified in
>   the second operand, or it must be of a type unambiguously derived from
>   that class.
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Explain a little more please?

Comment: It certainly does not define it, a definition of a pointer to member looks like `Type Class::*`

Comment: @K-ballo: Bad choice of words. I've been off caffeine for the past few days (from several cups a day) so my brain is like a scrambled egg.

Answer (score 2):

[Pointer-to-Member Operators: .* and ->*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx)

Comment: While not exactly an ideal answer, the article helped me figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The .* and ->* operators will point to member functions of a class or structure. The code below will show a simple example of how to use the .* operator, if you change the line:
`Value funcPtr = &Foo::One;` to `Value funcPtr = &Foo::Two;` the result displayed will change to 1000 since that function is `inValue*2`

for example [Taken From Here](http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Foo { 
  public: 
    double One( long inVal ) { return inVal*1; }
    double Two( long inVal ) { return inVal*2; }
}; 

typedef double (Foo::*Value)(long inVal); 

int main( int argc, char **argv ) { 
  Value funcPtr = &Foo::One; 

  Foo foo;

  double result = (foo.*funcPtr)(500); 
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0; 
}
```