# What is name of this operator ->*?

Tags: c++, operators

I have seen an example. in that example there is a line like `x->*y`. what is it? `->*`. I am new in C++ programming and I don't have much knowledge about operator. Can anybody describe it?

Comment: Not hard at all to check: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. Oh, and it isn't part of C.

Comment: It's not one operator. It's the `->` operator followed by the `*` operator.

Comment: @Barmar, It sure is in C++, and I don't think you can have that syntax in C.

Comment: @chris I have read that and i found some operator like `->`, `*` and `->*`. So, i am getting confused. Is it combination of two operator `->` and `*` or it just a single operator `->*` (Pointer to member)?

Comment: @Nimesh, It's a single operator. Those are three separate things. Tons of resources on each of them on Google and in books.

Comment: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr034.htm

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx

Comment: @Felix Same with [What are the Pointer-to-Member ->* and .* Operators in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c) Not sure why duplicates get upvoted.

Comment: @remyabel the only problem with the answers in these dupes is they're all seemingly centric on pointer to member *functions*, failing to fully cover that the operator is useful for pointer to member *everything*. For some reason member *variables* isn't covered well, and in most cases at-all. No clue why. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/10wnBm).

Comment: @FelixKling The link posted by remyabel is earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "pointer to member of pointer" and is one of the "pointer to member" type operators (in addition to `.*`, "pointer to member of object").

You can use it when you take the address of a member variable or function of a class, then you want to access that variable or call that function on an instance of that class, given a pointer to the instance (like a vanilla data or function pointer, but to a class member).

Here is an example using function pointers:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Example {
public:
  Example (int value) : value_(value) { }
  void printa (const char *s) { printf("A %i %s\n", value_, s); }
  void printb (const char *s) { printf("B %i %s\n", value_, s); }
private:
  int value_;
};

// print_member_ptr can point to any member of Example that
// takes const char * and returns void. 
typedef void (Example::* print_member_ptr) (const char *);

int main () {

  print_member_ptr ptr;
  Example x(1), y(2), *p = new Example(3), *q = new Example(4);

  ptr = &Example::printa;
  // .*ptr and ->*ptr will call printa
  (x.*ptr)("hello");
  (y.*ptr)("hello");
  (p->*ptr)("hello");
  (q->*ptr)("hello");

  ptr = &Example::printb;
  // now .*ptr and ->*ptr will call printb
  (x.*ptr)("again");
  (y.*ptr)("again");
  (p->*ptr)("again");
  (q->*ptr)("again");

}
```

The output is:

```
A 1 hello
A 2 hello
A 3 hello
A 4 hello
B 1 again
B 2 again
B 3 again
B 4 again
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Member pointed to by *b* of object pointed to by *a*.

**Syntax**

```
a->*b
```

**As member of K**

```
R &operator ->*(K a, S b);
```

**Outside class definitions**

```
R &K::operator ->*(S b);
```

See more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++).