# C++ Template with class method as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to pass a class method as a parameter to a template?  For example:

```
template<typename T, void(T::*TFun)()>
void call(T* x) {
    x->TFun();
}

struct Y {
    void foo();
};

int main() {
    Y y;
    call<Y,&Y::foo>(&y);  // should be the equivalent of y.foo()
}
```

If I try compiling the above, I get:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of void call(T*) [with T = Y; void (T::* TFun)() = &Y::foo]:
main.cpp:12:23:   required from here
main.cpp:4:5: error: struct Y has no member named TFun
     x->TFun();
     ^
```

Is this possible and if so, what's the syntax?

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates. Try it with a regular member function pointer.

Comment: [You may find **this** helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c), particularly the syntax in the last line of the accepted answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig,  thanks for the link, if I had found that before, I wouldn't have had to ask here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how you refer to a pointer-to-member. You need to dereference it first:

```
(x->*TFun)();
```

I used parenthesis do deal with operator precedence issues. `TFun` will be dereferenced before it is called.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I tried that syntax, but must have had it wrong or had some error.  It compiles now, though.