# c++ class method callback Similar to std::thread

Tags: c++, callback

Using std::thread you are able to pass a classes method as the function to call.

Syntax:

```
std::thread myThread(&MyClass::handler, this);
```

1.What is the syntax of my function to imitate this behavior to allow for passing of class methods to my own callback routines?

2.How do I store this reference in a variable?

ex:

```
Myclass temp;
myfunction(&Myclass::somefunc,temp);
```

So?

```
typedef void(*mycallbacktype)(const std::string& someperamiter);
void myfunction(???)
```

Comment: Look into `std::function`.

Comment: @user0042 Ok, so that seems to work.Any way to drop this to one line?:

    using std::placeholders::_1;
 callbacktype f_add_display2 = std::bind(&B::callbk, b, _1);
 s.startListen(f_add_display2);

Comment: See (3) in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Answer (score 1):

> 1.What is the syntax of my function to imitate this behavior to allow for passing of class methods to my own callback routines?

It is called "pointer-to-member". See [What are the Pointer-to-Member ->* and .* Operators in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c)
Your second question should be answered by that.

Answer (score 0):

To take a member function pointer to `MyClass` which returns void and takes no additional parameter declare it like -

```
void myfunction(void (MyClass::*somefunction)(), MyClass* obj)
{
  (obj->*somefunction)();
}
```

Here `void (MyClass::*somefunction)()` means `somefunction` is a pointer to member function of `MyClass` that takes no additional (except for implicit  `MyClass*` as first parameter) parameter and returns `void`. See [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) for more about member function pointer.

To make the function more generic like `std::thread` declare it as following- 
The first one takes any non-member function (aka. free function) of any type

```
template<class F, class... Args>  
void myfunction(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and second one takes the member function pointer of any type of any class.

```
template <class R, class C, class... Args> 
void myfunction(R(C::*mf)(Args...), C* pc, Args&&... args)
{
    (pc->*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```