# What is the meaning of this star (*) symbol in C++? -- Pointer to member

Tags: c++, pointers

In my project, there are a few lines in a `MyClass.h` file

```
class MyClass{
public:
....

#ifndef __MAKECINT__
  std::vector<Status_e(MyClass::*)(TupleInfo & info)> m_processObjects; //!
#endif
....
}
//The Status_e is an enum type
//The TupleInfo is a struct
```

I can't understand what the usage of this `*` in above code snippet. And in the `MyClass.cxx` file, the `m_processObjects` used as this:

```
for (unsigned int f = 0; f < m_processObjects.size(); ++f) {
    status = (this->*m_processObjects[f])( m_tuples[i] );
    if ( status == FAILURE ) {
      return EL::StatusCode::FAILURE;
    }
....
}
....
```

I have never heard about the usage like `this->*blabla`, but this code snippet works. So what it means?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members

Comment: Actually, the symbol is `::*`.

Comment: @RSahu The link for duplicate is not so lucky. Actually, a Q/A about pointer to member functions would match better e.g. [SO: Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485983/7478597).

Comment: Let's give this question another chance. Reopened. m_processObjects is a std::vector of function pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the Pointer-to-Member ->\* and .\* Operators in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`::*` denotes a [Pointer to member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member).

With the surrounding code it's actually a [Pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions).

```
Status_e(MyClass::*)(TupleInfo & info)
```

is a member function of `class MyClass`, returning `Status_e`, and having one parameter `TupleInfo&`. (The argument name `info` is useless here but obviously silently ignored by the compiler.)

The other snippet in OP's question shows how to call it:

```
status = (this->*m_processObjects[f])(m_tuples[i]);
```

Storing a method pointer would look like this:

```
std::vector<Status_e(MyClass::*)(TupleInfo & info)> m_processObjects;
```

...

```
m_processObjects.push_back(&MyClass::aMethod);
```

Of course, the signature of `MyClass::aMethod` must match.

A simplified sample to demonstrate it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
  
  private:
    std::vector<int(Test::*)(const char*)> _tblTestFuncs;
  public:
    Test()
    {
       _tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func1);
       _tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func2);
       _tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func3);
    }
  
    int func1(const char *caller) { std::cout << "Test::func1 called from '"<< caller << "': "; return 1; }
    int func2(const char *caller) { std::cout << "Test::func2 called from '"<< caller << "': "; return 2; }
    int func3(const char *caller) { std::cout << "Test::func3 called from '"<< caller << "': "; return 3; }
    
    void call()
    {
      for (size_t i = 0, n = _tblTestFuncs.size(); i < n; ++i) {
        int result = (this->*_tblTestFuncs[i])("Test::call()");
        std::cout << "Return: " << result << '\n';
      }
    }
};

int main()
{
  Test test;
  // test method vector in main()
  std::vector<int(Test::*)(const char*)> tblTestFuncs;
  tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func1);
  tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func2);
  tblTestFuncs.push_back(&Test::func3);
  for (size_t i = 0, n = tblTestFuncs.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    int result = (test.*tblTestFuncs[i])("main()");
    std::cout << "Return: " << result << '\n';
  }
  // test method vector in Test
  test.call();
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test::func1 called from 'main()': Return: 1
Test::func2 called from 'main()': Return: 2
Test::func3 called from 'main()': Return: 3
Test::func1 called from 'Test::call()': Return: 1
Test::func2 called from 'Test::call()': Return: 2
Test::func3 called from 'Test::call()': Return: 3
```

[**Live Demo on coliru.com**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55c5c8704a6be402)