# What is the behavior of a scoped function that contains (xxx::*)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've been trying to understand the purpose of some code I have been working with.  An argument of this form is being passed to a class constructor as a parameter.

```
(void (Callable::*)(IFN123Struct *, int))
```

It appears to be a function pointer but I am confused about the scope operators followed by the dereference operator with nothing following it.  What is happening here?  Does the function itself have a name?  What would be the purpose of doing this?

For the record, Callable appears to be an empty class.

Comment: That would be C++, not C.

Comment: Look up member function pointer.

Comment: Very similar question: [SO: What is the meaning of this star (*) symbol in C++? — Pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384782/7478597) (not literally but semantically).