# How to point to a function of a referenced class?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way to have a pointer to a function inside a referenced class?

I've tried replacing the reference to a class with another pointer, did not work.
I've also tried using `->` instead of `.`, no luck.

```
class First {
  void FunToPointTo();
};
class Second {
  First &reference;
  void (*pointer)();
  Second(First &first);
};

Second::Second(First &first) : reference(first) {
  pointer = reference.FunToPointTo;
}
```

Error: cannot convert 'First::FunToPointTo' from type 'void (First::)()' to type 'void (*)()'

Now I am trying to somehow make my pointer into `void (First::)()`, but I don't know the exact syntax.

Help is greatly appreciated, also please excuse my lack of knowledge as I am just starting c++.

Comment: You're looking for `void (First::*pointer)();`, and `&First::FunToPointTo`. Calling looks like `(object.*pointer)();`.

Comment: should be an answer @Quentin

Comment: Pointer on (function) member is different than Pointer on function.

Comment: No, it's of a different type, fundamentally incompatible with `void (*)()`.

Comment: @SamerTufail I don't think this question would be useful in the future, but it would be mean to leave OP hanging.

Comment: Look at [pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer), section "Pointers to member functions".

Comment: @Quentin I understand.

Comment: I once wrote an answer regarding member function pointers with a little sample: [SO: What is the meaning of this star (*) symbol in C++? — Pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384782/7478597). May be, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer type should be

```
void (First::*ptr)()
```

And assign with

```
&First::FunToPointTo
```

Since you need to specify the function is from class First.

Comment: I don't need a general 'FunToPointTo' I need the one inside the referenced class.

Comment: @OgnjenIlic I know but if you really think what a function is it's a piece of code that takes argumentsand if it's not a static function it has a pointer to the object named "this" . in this case you call the function with the object you want to send to the "this" keyword  like that :  reference.*ptr(); . Someone already wrote this I see

Comment: @Quentin:  See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions)

Comment: @wallyk your article clearly states you should use the & operator for member functions look at the pointer to member functions section. It is a good article btw

Comment: @Quentin:  tomer is quite right.  I have deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: @tomerzeitune:  Thanks.   I wonder why the rules are different for member functions?

Comment: @wallyk I think they are treated more like members rather than functions. It does make some sense

Comment: @wallyk as with many other quirks, this might be a remnant of compatibility with C.