# C++ compiler error (GCC) on class method parameter to function template

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I cannot understand why GCC generates an error on the following C++ code:

```
template<class T>
void f(T &x, void(T::*g)())
{
   x.g();
}

struct A
{
   void h(){;}
};

int
main(int, char*[])
{
   A a;
   f(a, &A::h);
   return 0;
}
```

This is what GCC generates as output when trying to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Weffc++ -c -fmessage-length=0 --std=c++2a -Weffc++ -o Main.o ../Main.cpp
../Main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f(T&, void (T::*)()) [with T = A]’:
../Main.cpp:16:13:   required from here
../Main.cpp:4:5: error: ‘struct A’ has no member named ‘g’
     4 |   x.g();
       |   ~~^
../Main.cpp:2:14: warning: unused parameter ‘g’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     2 | void f(T &x, void(T::*g)())
       |
```

GCC seems to look for a member 'g' of class A even though the method parameter has been instantiated with A's member function h.

Comment: `x.g()` doesn't look at your function parameter, you want `(x.*g)()`.

Comment: Yet another Q/A: [SO: What is the meaning of this star (*) symbol in C++? — Pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384782/7478597)