# Taking the address of a non-instantiated struct

Tags: c++

I am reading "C++ Templates. The Complete Guide. Second Edition", by David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis, Douglas Gregor. And, there is something that I don't understand.

This is one code example in pg. 59:

```
// define binary tree structure and traverse helpers:
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int i=0) : value(i), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    // ...
};

auto left = &Node::left;
auto right = &Node::right;

// traverse tree, using fold expression:
template<typename T, typename... TP>
Node* traverse (T np, TP... paths) {
    return (np ->* ... ->* paths);
}
// np ->* paths1 ->* paths2 ...

int main()
{
    // init binary tree structure:
    Node* root = new Node{0};
    root->left = new Node{1};
    root->left->right = new Node{2};
    // ...
    // traverse binary tree:
    Node* node = traverse(root, left, right);
    //...
}
```

What I don't understand is:

```
auto left = &Node::left;
auto right = &Node::right;
```

These are global variables of type (according to the llvm compiler): `Node *Node::*`. With value, for example the first one, `left`: `&Node::left`

The question is, being the variable `left` a pointer, how can I take the address (operator&) of a non-instantiated struct?

Comment: That is [pointer to member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member) syntax

Comment: See  [What are the Pointer-to-Member ->* and .* Operators in C++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-and-operators-in-c) for explanation (although it's not a "what is this" question. A "what is" question is  [c++ - What does void (M :: *pf)(int,int) = &M :: set_xy; do? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040711/what-does-void-m-pfint-int-m-set-xy-do))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an "a non-instantiated struct".

This is an address of a class member.

`left` is a member of the `Node` class. This takes its  "address", and not the actual address of some instance of some `Node` class. This does not take the `left` pointer of some particular class instance, but of the `left` ***itself***.

The address of a class member cannot be used just like that, by itself, but requires a ***specific*** instance of the class.

```
auto member_address = &Node::left;

// ...

Node *p;

// ...

Node *ptr=p->*member_address;
```

Whatever `p` is, this fetches `p`'s `left`. If `member_address` was `&Node::right`, `ptr` gets set to `p->right`.