# How to use format like (&Class::memberFunction, &class_instance) to pass parameters to the function of the variable parameter template

Tags: c++, templates

std::thread and std::bind can use member function as parameters like this:

```
class X{
public:
  void do_lengthy_work();
};

X my_x;
std::thread t(&X::do_lengthy_work,&my_x);
```

Then in my own code

```
class thread_pool {
  ...
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) {

    auto func = [f = std::move(f), &args...]() {
      f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()> task(func);
    std::future<decltype(f(args...))> res(task.get_future());
    if (local_work_queue) {
      local_work_queue->push(std::move(task));
    } else {
      pool_work_queue.push(std::move(task));
    }
    return res;
  }

};

class Test {
 public:
  void print_one() { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; }
  void print_zero() { std::cout << "0" << std::endl; }
};
void print() { std::cout << "0" << std::endl; }
void print_n(int number) { std::cout << number << std::endl; }

int main() {
  thread_pool pool;
  Test test;
  auto f1 = pool.submit(&Test::print_one, &test);//(1)wrong
  auto f2 = pool.submit([&test]() { test.print_one(); });
  int n = 3;
  auto f3 = pool.submit(print_n, std::move(n));
  auto f4 = pool.submit(print);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
  return 0;
}
```

(1) reports an error, the specific information is:
called object type 'remove_reference_t<void (Test::*&)()>' (aka 'void (Test::*)()') is not a function or function pointer

Does this way of writing require other processing besides variable parameter templates?

==========================================================
According to @wearetherobots and @Igor Tandetnik's answer,I change it to

```
auto func = [f, args...]() mutable {
  return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Comment: I bet, you should use `F(Args...)` as template argument for `std::packaged_task` and `std::future`

Comment: Are you using clang? gcc gives a more direct error message: "error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f) (...)'" *Also, that took more work than it should have to eliminate the extraneous errors when I copied your code to a compiler.*

Comment: Rather than directly calling the function like `f(args...)`, do `std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. It is `std::invoke` that knows how to deal with a pointer to member function, and a few other special cases.

Comment: `func` doesn't return any value, but you attempt to wrap it into `std::packaged_task<T()>` where `T` may not be `void`. You either want `std::packaged_task<void()>`, or have `func` return the result of the `f` call.

Comment: `func` captures `args` by reference, but may be called after `submit` returns, by which time those references may be dangling.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I can use mutable lambda besides reference.

Comment: [How to call through a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer) and [What are the pointer-to-member operators ->* and .* in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586205/what-are-the-pointer-to-member-operators-and-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The invocation of a member function pointer `pmfn` on an object reference `obj` is not done with the syntax `(*pmnf)(obj, ...)`, but instead `(obj.*pmfn)(...)`.

You can use `std::function<>` (to define a callable object) or `std::invoke()` (to do the invocation), which will deal with this syntactic aspect for you.  I think `std::invoke` is more suitable to your use case:

```
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) {

    auto func = [f = std::move(f), &args...]() {
      std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  ...
  }
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: Thank you! From C++ 17,std::invoke can be used to unify ordinary and member function-call syntax cases.